# Homebrew game-designing problem: Ranged unit attack roll in Large-scale Battle?

Tags: game-design, ranged-attack, attack-roll, mass-combat

I've run into a little homebrew game-designing issue and maybe you may have just the creative solution I'm looking for. I'll try to explain this as best as I can!

- I've been trying to create an intelligent solution for a "platoon ranged attack roll" in a large-scale battle and I just cannot seem to find the creative mathematical solution for it. (We're aiming for something simple, realistic and dynamic.)

To illustrate how our large scale battles system works when two melee infantry regiments meet:

- Regiment 1: d20 + basic modifiers: (Morale+Stamina+Cohesion+Experience)

  vs.
- The Regiment 2, same basic modifiers.

The same was supposed to work when a ranged regiment is attacking another regiment (with slightly different modifiers):

- The Regiment that is being shot at (Morale+Cohesion+Armor+Attention):

  Rough example: d20 + Morale(Steady 0) + Cohesion (Disciplined tight formation 2) + Armor (linen+shield 1+3) + Attention (Not engaged 0) = d20+6

  vs.
- Ranged Regiment: (Missile+Accuracy+Weather+Range + Numbers)

  Rough example: d20 + Missile type (Bows&arrows 0) + Accuracy (High Accuracy 1) + Weather conditions (Zero wind 1) + Range ( -3) + Numbers (40 Archers) = d20-1 and... 40 Archers.

What do I do with those "40 Archers"? I'm quite lost and cannot find a creative way to solve this "math problem." I'd appreciate it so much if you could offer your insight! How do we make a reasonable roll so that the number of ranged units in a regiment also plays a role in that ranged attack roll? I'm unfortunately not familiar with many RPGs, so if you know a good system that resembles what I'm trying to go for here, I'd be thankful if you shared that too.

P.S.: Our aim was also not to use HP and count casualties only after the battle is over. What we do instead is that when a regiment loses a roll in a combat exchange, its modifiers change. So for example, an infantry regiment is being beaten by another infantry, it first loses stamina, then cohesion and morale, until the whole regiment breaks and flees the field.

Comment: What's the possible range of those parenthetical modifiers?  That is, can the weather modifier go from +10 (sun overhead on a cloudless day in flat terrain) to -50 (on a moonless night during a hurricane) or do they range instead from +1 to -5 or something else? Or has that yet to be decided?

Comment: Also, welcome to this stack! I'm not sure this is the best stack for this question—Board and Card Games might be better—, but this stack does field questions about semi-RPGs like *Car Wars* and such, so it may be okay. (It might help the question stay open to include—even in an unrelated note—how role-playing elements influence unit statistics, though!) Anyway, good luck, thank you for participating, and have fun!

Comment: I'm voting to close as opinion-based, since I'm not seeing a good way to determine answer quality here. It seems like any answer with a creative solution to the numbers problem would be equally good by the text of the question, and there isn't a metric to determine which answer would be the best. It feels like an idea-generation question to me, which is probably better suited to a [forum](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449) than this site.

Comment: Why do you count the size of the unit for ranged attacks but not for melee?

Comment: Also, define and rank order for us your criteria for success. You say "simple, realistic, and dynamic", but there is tension between those three. Simple is almost always the enemy of realistic, in my experience, and dynamic can mean a lot of things.

Comment: @Hey I Can Chan, Thanks for the warm welcome! :) The range of those modifiers are not yet final and fully decided. We expect to do a lot of adjusting after we beging playing. But my expectation is that the modifiers would be ranging from +10 to -10 max. So far, the most figures (average) range between +3 to -3.
Anyway, to the forum I go! :)

Comment: @Paul , I count the ranged units, because all of them participate in a ranged attack - a volley - and should be taken into account (Alas, I do not know how to do it yet, hence my question here). Whereas in a melee exchange, only the first row participates (and in some cases, second row too), therefore the number of troops in a melee attack is not as important. Other factors are. Throughout the melee battle, as long as the formation held, not many soldiers died. The slaughter only began as the formation began to break and the system was supposed to represent that.

Comment: Of course, each melee infantry regiment will have its own number of soldiers. And at the end of the battle, based on the number of attacks it had received and failed (and other factors), casualties will be counted for each regiment.
I seek a simple set of rules, that does not bother the DM to do a lot of counting, but allows the action to flow, where all the DM needs to do during the battle is change the modifier of each relevant regiment. That's what I also meant by "dynamic". 
Realistic, well, that's a bit harder to describe (HP is unrealistic) and perhaps I should have omitted that.

Comment: Well, they put you on hold for primarily opinion based, which is too bad as I was working up to an answer.  Maybe there's a way to make your question more specific that'll remove the block, I don't know.

Comment: @Paul See [this FAQ](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6533/321) for why your comments were redacted/removed. Thanks!

Comment: @SevenSidedDie it wasn't an answer at all, it was a recommendation to look at how existing games work. That doesn't at all address his question.

Comment: @Paul That response is already addressed in the FAQ. Rather than repeating it, I will just let the FAQ explain how that’s still actionable when submitted in a comment.

Comment: Did you really delete his recommendations? ...Thanks for that... I understand there are certain quality control mechanisms on this site, but sometimes I feel like the line between quality control and absurdity gets really blurred here. Is this what the rules are for? Who creates these rules? And why would you enforce something like that? 
It reminds me of pre-1989 Eastern Bloc countries, when people followed and enforced rules, just because they had to be followed and enforced, even if they went against common sense.

Comment: @Jotunn The rules aren’t mindless. They are to enforce how to use the site appropriately. I.e., if you want answers, you need to fix the question such that its answer section gets reopened. If you don’t want to do that, that’s fine, but the comments aren’t here to help answer questions that are off topic.

Answer (score -1):

Off the bat, there are already a lot of modifiers going into it. :) There are a couple of ways you could approach it, but some thoughts:

Why don't you have each unit that moves represent a platoon instead of individual soldiers? If you both have squad-based combat where each marker would indicate one soldier AND where each indicator would be a squad, then you'd want to keep the rules relatively similar. So, you would just use the same ruleset and have each marker/token represent 12, 20, however many archers are in a squad.

Alternatively, you mentioned a d20 as a base. Make the d20 represent 20 soldiers, which have health states like:

- d20 - Full health
- d12 - Losses
- d6 - Crippling Losses

So, your base attack modifier would drop significantly based on the number of remaining soldiers. Yes, this is getting closer to HP, but it's not tracking beyond a few levels, and it sounds like the cohesion/morale system would be more complex.

This would, however, make even a damaged unit much harder to hurt a full-health squad. For that, don't have the defenders roll dice. I've found in a lot of tactical games it's best to make the dice roll represent one single thing - in this case, attacking. Outside of attacking, dice shouldn't be rolled. Off the bat, this sounds like it would make it hard to have a complex game - in practice, it just makes it more approachable and consistent, so you're not going d20 against d20.

This changes the game so your defender's ability to survive would be based entirely on their use of terrain, cohesion, skill, and other modifiers. Give cover and terrain more of a benefit - this would be more realistic, since you can't really dodge a bullet, but you can hunker down and if you're smart, reduce the odds of you getting shot.

Since it's your game, though, you'd need to figure out what makes the most sense for your players. A system can work for one group of people but not another, so you're probably going to have to play a few different methods, try some features, and maybe pick up a couple tabletop tactics games to see how they approach it - numbered die aren't the only dice out there, so consider some with custom faces where depending on what comes up it would represent a solid hit, a weak hit, or a miss, and the more archers you have changes how many dice you roll.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Hi, and welcome to RPG Stack Exchange! The advice that you give hear seems like it's coming from a good place, but it runs afoul of one of the core rules of the site, namely "Back It Up!" On RPG.SE, if you want to include homebrew in your answer, you have to back it up with experience of actually running that homebrew. It's easy to come up with ideas for how to solve things, but it's really hard to know if an answer actually works without playtesting it first.